# eMail Hidden Recipient

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

Not sure if its the correct place to ask...
Lets say i am going to send an email to two recipients

`TO: field`  **recipient**
`bbc: field` **hidden recipient**

When the **recipient** uses *Reply to All* to answer my mail, will the  **hidden recipient** receive his answer too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, he won't.

Just the way bcc works -- recipient won't receive any traces of that there was any other repicients and therefore he won't be able to include him in recipients for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Because to do so that recipient would have to be revealed to the main recipients software (and therefore to the main recipients). Your email recieved by recipient should contain no trace that it was BCC'd to another person.